# userQuery is undefined in <Route />

Tags: reactjs, query-string, reactivesearch

I'm just about done building my search UI with ReactiveSearch and just need to figure out how to display the results on '/results' with React Router 4 and npm package query-string.

I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/znwp1lj1jl) here

My question is why is the `userQuery` undefined? I thought I followed [this](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-query-strings/) correctly?

Basically my search-layout.js is like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import querystring from 'query-string';

import Results from '../components/search/Results';

class SearchLayout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(value) {
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value });
    console.log('This is the value: ', value);
    const userQuery = querystring.parse(this.props.location.search);
    // this.setState({ userQuery: this.state.userQuery });
    console.log('This is from query-string: ', userQuery);
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    console.log('This is value: ', value);
    const { userQuery } = this.state; // query string
    console.log('This is the userQuery: ', userQuery);
    const { match } = this.props; // path
    console.log('This is match props: ', match);

    return (
      <div>
        <Route path={`${match.path}?q=${userQuery}`} component={Results} />
        {this.state.value}
        {match.path}
        <br />
        {match.url}
        <br />
        {/* <Results /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchLayout;
```

The Results component that `<Route />` is rendering contains the ReactiveList component. I know `<Results />` works and displays the information because I originally just had React render it - just to make sure it worked. Now I'm trying to integrate RR4 and the query-string package and not sure where I'm going wrong.

If I replace **path={`${match.path}?q="${userQuery}"`}** with **path="/results"** - results display, but not based on the user query, its just default ReactiveList behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first lets see what you pass to `query-string` and what `query-string` want, for example we pass enter aaa in text box you pass `?q="aaa"` but query-string want `?q=aaa`

so lets remove `""` around over query stirng :

```
 const fixedQuery = this.props.location.search.replace(/['"]+/g, "");
 console.log(fixedQuery );
 const userQuery = querystring.parse(fixedQuery );
 console.log(JSON.stringify(userQuery));
 console.log(JSON.stringify(userQuery.q));
```

please check this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6lo62q7wzn)

Comment: it works! userQuery is defined! I though fixing the undefined would fix everything but the results still don't display... but I'll keep working at it.

Comment: I just noticed I had querystring from "query-string" INSTEAD of queryString from "query-string" and yet the code seems to still work :)